# Process QDBusPendingCallWatcher results in PyQt4?

Tags: pyqt4, dbus, qtdbus

I'd like to make a non-blocking call to a function in a remote D-Bus service using PyQt4.QtDBus. Adapting from Qt's C++ documentation, I came up with the following test program:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtDBus

class DeviceInterface(QtDBus.QDBusAbstractInterface):

    def __init__(self, service, path, connection, parent=None):
        super().__init__(service, path, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device',
                         connection, parent)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtDBus.QDBusArgument)
    def callFinishedSlot(self, arg):
        print("Got result:", arg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    dev = DeviceInterface('org.freedesktop.UDisks',
                          '/org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda1',
                          QtDBus.QDBusConnection.systemBus(), app)

    async = dev.asyncCall("FilesystemListOpenFiles");
    watcher = QtDBus.QDBusPendingCallWatcher(async, dev)
    watcher.finished.connect(dev.callFinishedSlot)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It seems to work. When I run it, it prints:

```
Got result: <PyQt4.QtDBus.QDBusPendingCallWatcher object at 0xb740c77c>
```

The problem is, I don't know how to convert the `QDBusPendingCallWatcher` to something (e.g., `QDBusMessage`) that I can extract the results from. The example from the [C++ documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdbuspendingcallwatcher.html) does this:

```
 void MyClass.callFinishedSlot(QDBusPendingCallWatcher *call)
 {
     QDBusPendingReply<QString, QByteArray> reply = *call;
     if (reply.isError()) {
         showError();
     } else {
         QString text = reply.argumentAt<0>();
         QByteArray data = reply.argumentAt<1>();
         showReply(text, data);
     }
     call->deleteLater();
 }
```

Can anyone tell me how to translate the C++ slot to something that will work with PyQt4? (I'm using PyQt4.9.1 with Qt 4.8.1.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the trick seems to be to construct a `QDBusPendingReply` from the `QDBusPendingCallWatcher` instance (many thanks to Phil Thompson for pointing this out on the [PyQt mailing list](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2012-August/031820.html)). As it turns out, this same technique also works in C++. I had the UDisk object path wrong in my original code, plus a few other minor typos, so here's a complete, working example for posterity:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtDBus

class DeviceInterface(QtDBus.QDBusAbstractInterface):

    def __init__(self, service, path, connection, parent=None):
        super().__init__(service, path, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device',
                         connection, parent)

    def callFinishedSlot(self, call):
        # Construct a reply object from the QDBusPendingCallWatcher
        reply = QtDBus.QDBusPendingReply(call)
        if reply.isError():
            print(reply.error().message())
        else:
            print("  PID        UID     COMMAND")
            print("-------    -------   ------------------------------------")
            for pid, uid, cmd in reply.argumentAt(0):
                print("{0:>7d}    {1:>7d}   {2}".format(pid, uid, cmd))
        # Important: Tell Qt we are finished processing this message
        call.deleteLater()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import signal
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    dev = DeviceInterface('org.freedesktop.UDisks',
                          '/org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda1',
                          QtDBus.QDBusConnection.systemBus(), app)

    async = dev.asyncCall("FilesystemListOpenFiles");
    watcher = QtDBus.QDBusPendingCallWatcher(async, dev)
    watcher.finished.connect(dev.callFinishedSlot)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This should work on most recent Linux distros, and is a good example of using PyQt to invoke a D-Bus method that returns a compound type.